# What type of wait should I use for sendKeys function for an element ? Python Selenium

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given I have to use sendKeys to set a value for an element attribute which might load slowly or is obstructed by a animation, what type of wait for elemnt should I use?

At the moment I use visibility_of_element_located from selenium's expected_conditions library, but for some reason, sometimes, the typing is not done, the cursor is blinking on the element, as if it was found but no value is inserted.

I'm not sure if visibility_of_element_located is the right usecase here, do you guys have any suggestions here?

EDIT: This is a more 'pick ur brain' type of question, while I wish to learn better usecases, if any apply to what i've described above. If any other info is required I'm happy to enrich here.

Method which I call with xpath and value, as mandatory input :

```
    def type_js(self, xpath, value, enter=None, priority=None, enable_Logging=True, js=None, classValue=None, forLoopPause=0.1, type_Token=False):

    if isinstance(value, int) == True:
        value = str(value)

    if enable_Logging == True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
            elemnt = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            elemnt.clear()

            if type_Token == True:
                elemnt.click()
                from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
                for i in list(value):
                    # elemnt.send_keys(i)
                    keyboard = Controller()
                    keyboard.press(str(i))
                    keyboard.release(str(i))
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                if js == True:
                    self.browser.execute_script(
                        "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{}');".format(value.replace('\n', '')),
                        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("{}".format(xpath)))
                else:
                    for i in list('{}'.format(value)):
                        elemnt.send_keys(i)
                        time.sleep(forLoopPause)
                    if enter != None:
                        elemnt.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

            utilities.loggingObj.priority_handler(xpath=xpath, priority=priority, action_type='Type',
                                                     isException=False, browser=self.browser)

        except(NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException) as e:
            print(
                'exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}\nException Stack Trace : {}'.format(str(e), xpath,
                                                                                   e))
            utilities.loggingObj.priority_handler(xpath=xpath, priority=priority, action_type='Type',
                                                     isException=True,
                                                     exeption='exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}\nException Stack Trace : {}'.format(
                                                         str(e), xpath,
                                                         e), browser=self.browser)
            return False

        except(TimeoutException) as e_timeout:
            print(
                'exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}\nException Stack Trace : Elementul nu a fost vizibil pe pagina in 3 sec de wait (TimeoutException)'.format(
                    str(e_timeout), xpath))
            utilities.loggingObj.priority_handler(xpath=xpath, priority=priority, action_type='Type',
                                                     isException=True, exeption=
                                                     'exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}\nException Stack Trace : Elementul nu a fost vizibil pe pagina in 3 sec de wait (TimeoutException)'.format(
                                                         str(e_timeout), xpath), browser=self.browser)
```

Comment: You can use element to be clickable. If nothing works try java script executor. Update question with more information related to code, logs and the screen image.

Comment: The problem occurs once or twice every 50 tests ran, will updated with the method that I use for typing asap. While this wasn't the goal of the post

Comment: I think you have to use 'clickable' at `WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))` instead of checking for the visibility of the element.

Comment: Yup, that's what I used to use, but i thought that there is some other function that I didn't read about or some smarter way to approach this. While I do consider 'clickable' to be better in this scenario, yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look over the waits - it might help you [Python Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

> Selenium Webdriver provides two types of waits - implicit & explicit.
> An explicit wait makes WebDriver wait for a certain condition to occur
> before proceeding further with execution. An implicit wait makes
> WebDriver poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to
> locate an element.

Comment: Read these mate, I was wondering if my usecase was not optimal. Thanks tho!